# Inline-block elements of the same height in a few lines

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Can I do all the blocks of the same height without JS and min-height (as a special case)? Blocks can be placed on multiple lines.

Example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kombat003/yzg2vx46/1/)

[image: Correct height]

```css
ul {
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  background: grey;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option, then you can make `ul` a *wrapping* `flexbox`.

**How this works?**

1. `display: flex` creates a *flexbox* which has the property to distribute whitespace between its children in various ways.
2. `flex-wrap: wrap` allows the `li`s to go to the next line depending on the content
3. `justify-content: center` does horizontal centering.
4. Vertically the `li`s have a property called `align-items: stretch`, which is the default - this allows the heights of the `li`s to be equal in a line.

See demo below:

```css
ul {
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}

li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  background: grey;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Easily, using `display: flex`.
Specify the orientation + wrapping in `flex-flow: row wrap;` and the central alignment in `justify-content: center;`

Example:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  background: grey;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
</ul>
```